# Getting value error when trying to use numpy to merge alpha images

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to follow an example here:
https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-numpy-alpha-blend-mask/

and my code works fine up until the final two lines.  So this part is working...

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
```

...

```
im1 = Image.open("G:\\u3road3.jpg")
im2 = Image.open("G:\\u3road1.jpg").resize(im1.size,Image.BILINEAR)

mask = Image.open("G:\\u3RoadMask2.jpg").convert('L')
mask2 = mask.resize(im1.size,Image.BILINEAR)

src1 = np.array(im1)
src2 = np.array(im2)
mask1 = np.array(mask2)
mask1 = mask1 / 255
```

...

but if I add this line it fails with a "ValueError":

```
dst = src1 * mask1 + src2 * (1 - mask1)
```

so I don't even get to the last line where I save my image out:

```
Image.fromarray(dst.astype(np.uint8)).save('G:/testes.jpg')
```

Anyone have any ideas what I can try next?

Comment: Full-stack trace, please? What version of OpenCV are you using? Where are your debug prints? What have you tried other than this?

Comment: Not using OpenCV that I know of.  Just installed numpy.  Since I'm only copying code I don't really have anything else to try.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that. I just assume you were using it because the tutorial was basically based on OpenCV.

Comment: What's the actual error message?  Lots of things can produce a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of your Numpy arrays. I mean:

```
print(src1.dtype, src2.dtype, mask1.dtype)
```

They are almost certainly `uint8` which means whole numbers between 0 and 255. When you divide a number in that range by 255, you are going to get a lot of zeroes, whereas you actually want a lot of floating point numbers between 0 and 1.

Try instead dividing by 255.0 and check the `dtype` then.

Comment: Yes, they are uint8 and dividing the mask by 255.0 gives me a float64.  But I still get an error the next line down, but even dividing src1 and src2 by 1.0 (getting another float64) still gives me that ValueError in that next line.  So I'm still confused as to what to do next.

Comment: Can you please share your actual images, and your actual, complete runnable code and the actual complete error message. It's easier dealing with specifics